# Internet speed extremely slow in terminal but fast on browser

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, internet

I am facing extremely slow internet speed in the terminal while downloading packages. Currently my browser speed is 3mbps(measured using fast.com), and I also downloaded files that got downloaded on **400kB/s** from browser, but from terminal when I am installing `tensorflow` using `pip3` the speed ranges from **20kB/s-30kB/s**.
Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Changed the mirrors from **Software and Updates** by selecting **best server**.
2. Disable the **IPv6** from Wi-Fi settings.
3. Updated the system by `apt-get`.
4. Removed `#` from `precedence::fff:0:0/96 100` located in `/etc/gai.conf`

Rebooted after every changes. Please help me in solving the issue!
Thanks in advance

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You can't compare speed when downloading from different servers. It has nothing to do with terminal or web browser.