# Ubuntu 21.10 Slow Wifi

Tags: networking, drivers

Just installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my laptop and wifi is terribly slow.

The speedtest often shows about 4 Mbps and in the best case it reaches 30 Mbps. However, when I connect it to the same network, but through the USB Mobile Hotspot, it reaches about 110 Mbps (which is what I expect).

I've tried many proposed solutions such as:

- Disabling wifi power management,
- Disabling IPv6,
- Removing iwlwifi packages

But it still doesn't work.

I suspected it could be a hardware problem, but previously it worked properly on Windows 11. I've been using Ubuntu for a while in other laptops and I didn't have a problem like this before.

My current laptop is a Asus X541U and the hardware is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter.

Comment: See my answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346448/internet-speed-extremely-slow-in-terminal-but-fast-on-browser/1346462#1346462

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internet speed extremely slow in terminal but fast on browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346448/internet-speed-extremely-slow-in-terminal-but-fast-on-browser)

Comment: No, it doesn't. MTU is by default set to 1500, so I think it is OK.

Comment: It's not OK, as I explained in my answer. The part starting with: The `MTU` (Maximum Transmission Unit) is the size of the largest packet that can be sent in a single network transmission. If a packet exceeds the  `MTU` of a link, the data must be split into multiple packets (fragmented). These multiple packets must be sent over the link, received, acknowledged, and reassembled at the far end. If your link is misconfigured, and you have to fragment every packet you send, your actual data transfer rate drops.